# Windows Container - Using the "--mount" option when creating a service seems to make the run fail

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-swarm

I have a Docker Swarm cluster with cloud VMs and when I'm trying to run a container with the "--mount" options instead of the "-v" option (because it doesn't exist on `docker service create`, I get the following error:

```
"starting container failed: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 1a2e90d47b6293fbd3be7168c93c110ff8cc620733b3ad8fe0d77de0c60ee5e3: The request is not supported.
(extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"1a2e90d47b6293fbd3be7168c93c110ff8cc620733b3ad8fe0d77de0c60ee5e3","Owner":"docker","VolumePath":"\\\\?\\Volume{a18f50d0-153f-4b54-8e81-c297317d2136}","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\1a2e90d47b6293fbd3be7168c93c110ff8cc620733b3ad8fe0d77de0c60ee5e3","Layers":[{"ID":"4381cd23-3415-50e7-a31f-cc48646ad7c7","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\8425a66cc59c577ece9be2e9969fc18b27df0b8b9d93f718b92c04bbb17bf28e"},{"ID":"6cf9bec4-9afe-52a1-81d6-e18e419df8f1","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\0878961a7b84cd31a8b1f3928085af81a84227efd91ceae6a2e0eac44997b45e"},{"ID":"86deebca-0ae1-5344-b771-063f2ad38e54","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\31a7c11425d770dd65dc44bca828ac16dc72b9a59742a34f794d655ffeb8c073"},{"ID":"46e038a7-7bea-5c1d-87d6-d6d3048dacd0","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\a365eb45c0d7dda81507ac878f89e4e268e815285471919e8fa4b0b472dae9cf"},{"ID":"0717381c-d70d-584a-ba8d-c963b97cf8f1","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\39cb1cd4b050631643533fffdc40ca4fbc827f216a6181632544b2b655bfc26e"},{"ID":"8c52bac8-0d75-5338-bb16-003f64cf0198","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\4e2c07c945e6d32deafa21d3b28a858c3b3c14ea9740ff975317aae81d3d2237"},{"ID":"f944baab-2ed4-549a-88a6-dda7aa6f20cf","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\c02bbae1e2a48db238de78ac82077252d40819700ed6413b7eee4cd24cd4434f"},{"ID":"75926c63-459b-55db-8f37-a35c79430bb4","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\9a449444e233cae47fbf831fb9118a1d525317f3f4cf0592793ecc7c00909489"},{"ID":"ba1dff8b-3eae-5a7d-b6f5-8a6ef86e0152","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\68c24c7fec32a2da03a4f11f5971afcfd1da772c3be09f91f93905c2814443ac"},{"ID":"9f8badee-42d8-5b22-9388-79a68addebe9","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\b3ff27c178ce49f20255c9b4d88705db01014baee31772b7f9de3b0426ff7ca9"},{"ID":"90a79b7b-4f75-5d13-b500-b3ab60871059","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\bbdd9c2ad84ab7e3c00940f95982b3e0e8ae64cbf022a36ca773d1645b796973"},{"ID":"2488fb23-500a-566b-97bc-6f9133b8dd56","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\1e81d276ba3ed87ed714e4b8af301daceddad943d38ba8eb6650016017453060"},{"ID":"704560d1-f2c5-5c6d-80be-02c894b44221","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\63978c584fc9184dcd6f7c2ec953b3e1ac587258e2462ad109c21de645665cd8"},{"ID":"d670d883-6d44-5a13-a8bd-41177d3f2ac8","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\3a6adae0488abd9a76be82f4f71727961159dfb8a05e5fe4ba8252a00d2f7274"},{"ID":"5868eb58-5d45-5aa6-aee0-a5ad05cbf269","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\8cb7eb98fbd1d1055f3b9ca695b25cacf84889625777a29edd436c5e9f390379"},{"ID":"3995d88f-3647-560c-b321-39d7795412bd","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\181a1893c651374b59f1f2868b754423c9215f556cacb61eea468eec9e1c9273"},{"ID":"431cbb9a-e9be-5436-9c17-7ae8575aada3","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\5ecfa22985c2cb214719b79bbea1bc791b2aa4c99a7db6ee0cfd3432aa4d218a"},{"ID":"750fbc48-f9c1-55bc-8512-0af61aeb0a95","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\ca63b6af8c5d92ca093521e944838a435dd26bfb2b85c37bd9f93a2b47976a29"},{"ID":"e3ae4f7e-fa3d-5b6d-bf85-b33411a80627","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\5dec0053be676f1f7181f8059101b54e4a7d96b524fa98beea67e48737fc6b11"}],"ProcessorMaximum":10000,"MemoryMaximumInMB":4096,"HostName":"database","MappedDirectories":[{"HostPath":"G:\\sql","ContainerPath":"C:\\wfgen\\sql","ReadOnly":false,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false},{"HostPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\volumes\\f1e4209f9d802e1293a904ce423c43efbf377d0e5857e794963fa0261f070605\\_data","ContainerPath":"c:\\wfgen\\sql","ReadOnly":false,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false},{"HostPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\containers\\1a2e90d47b6293fbd3be7168c93c110ff8cc620733b3ad8fe0d77de0c60ee5e3\\mounts\\secrets","ContainerPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\internal\\secrets","ReadOnly":true,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false}],"HvPartition":false,"EndpointList":["36888706-13FA-4C3D-9C6D-2936E4CC557B"],"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true})"
```

The actual command that I use:

```
docker service create `
  --name database `
  --env-file .\database.env `
  --mount 'type=bind,src=G:/sql,dst=C:/wfgen/sql' `
  --secret SA_PASSWORD `
  --secret WFGEN_DATABASE_USER_USERNAME `
  --secret WFGEN_DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD `
  --secret WFGEN_ADMIN_PASSWORD `
  --limit-cpu '2' `
  --limit-memory '4G' `
  --hostname database `
  advantys/workflowgen-sql-express:7.15.5-win-ltsc2019
```

If I remove the "--mount" parameter, it works fine. Also, the same error happens when not in a Swarm on my Windows 10 using the same parameter. But, again, using the "-v" parameter works just fine.

I searched the web and Github (moby/moby and docker-for-win) for people who
may have the same problem but I can't find anything. Is there someone who
encountered a similar error that can give me answers on why this doesn't work
or pointers for answers?

Version Information:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Version:           19.03.1
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.5
 Git commit:        f660560464
 Built:             07/25/2019 20:59:52
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.1
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.12.5
  Git commit:       f660560464
  Built:            07/25/2019 20:57:41
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```